# Where is the date of last change in the XML files of a DOCX?

Tags: regex, xml, docx

I've unzipped a DOCX-document and am looking for the date or time for the file's last change.

I've tried using command line tools like `grep` but to no avail.

When I upload the DOCX-file to Google Docs, it does find the date.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked in `docProps/core.xml`? It has the `/cp:coreProperties/dcterms:modified` tag:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cp:coreProperties xmlns:...>
    ...
    <cp:lastModifiedBy>Administrator</cp:lastModifiedBy>
    <cp:revision>2</cp:revision>
    <dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2021-04-02T14:33:00Z</dcterms:created>
    <dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2021-04-02T14:34:00Z</dcterms:modified>
</cp:coreProperties>
```

Also remember that Zip and most other archives have fields to store the modification date *of the archived files themselves:*

```
$ zipinfo Untitled\ document.docx
Archive:  Untitled document.docx
Zip file size: 6095 bytes, number of entries: 9
-rw----     2.0 fat     1341 bl defN 21-Apr-02 07:42 word/numbering.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     1770 bl defN 21-Apr-02 07:42 word/settings.xml
...
```

Usually this modification time is preserved also when you extract the file. Interestingly, Microsoft Word *doesn't* use this field, always storing the same constant zero value.

Comment: That would definitely have been it, but the unzipped file doesn't include the file! It shouldn't matter that the file is from Google Docs, right?

Comment: It might, I don't know where Google takes it from but I have suspicions.

Comment: "zipinfo" worked! I had no idea. Amazing!

Comment: Keep in mind that these dates are easily manipulated.

Comment: It might be noteworthy that a to-spec OOXML file has all file modification dates set to 1/1/1980 00:00 in the ZIP archive, so that source of information is not reliable.